# How to find the folder path in a test case in test plan of "Micro Focus Application Lifecycle Management (ALM)"?

Tags: testing, alm, hp-alm, test-plan

I am trying to find the folder path in a test case in test plan of "Micro Focus Application Lifecycle Management (ALM)" previously know as HP ALM.
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no field in Test Lab that gives you path of a test case in test plan, but you can navigate from a test instance in Test Lab to corresponding test case in Test Plan. You can right click on the Test instance and click on "Go to Test in Test Plan" [Navigate to test case in Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYR5p.png)
Is that what you are looking for?

If you are specifically looking for a way to find the path of test case in test plan from test lab test case instance, you may have to depend on ALM SQL queries.